# Keyboard hide editext in twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter

[image]Hi i am facing a problem in twitter integration keyboard hide username edittext i have attached the screen-shot for what is the problem .Thanks in advance 
 screen-shot is the problem.

[image]

One more thing i dont want to change my SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution :- I have replace twitter dialog code from latest sdk and it is working

Answer (score 0):

**

> You can use this code. May be solve this problem. put the code in
>   OnCreate() method.

**

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ivAppSearch))
                            .getWindowToken(), 0);

**or**

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);